# How to pass many ajax results to different input values?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

My ajax return results are four values.I want assign these values to four input value.Here my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url:"modify_cbndtb.php",
 data: {cabinetNum:id},
 success:function (res) 
 {
 } 
});
```

modify_cbndtb.php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['cabinetNum']))
{   
 $q=$_POST["cabinetNum"];
 $sql="select num1,num2,num3,num4 from  hpc WHERE sysid= '".$q."';";
 $sel = $conn->query($sql);
}
```

My html code:

```
<div id="content" class="content">
1U:<input type="text" id="1U" value="">11U:<input type="text" id="11U" value=""><br />
2U:<input type="text" id="2U" value="">12U:<input type="text" id="12U" value=""><br />
</div>
```

1U.value should be num1. 2U.value should be num2. 3U.value should be num3. 4U.value should be num4. But I don't know how to realize. Who can help me?

Comment: I'm not a PHP guy, but the PHP code shown doesn't seem to output anything. Send the response in JSON format and then you can easily manage the values in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try this

```
modify_cbndtb.php

  if(isset($_POST['cabinetNum']))
  {   
     $q=$_POST["cabinetNum"];
     $sql="select num1,num2,num3,num4 from  hpc WHERE sysid= '".$q."';";
     $sel = $conn->query($sql);
     $arr = $sel->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $data = json_encode($arr);
     echo $data;
  }
```

and AJAX

```
 client file

 $.ajax({
 type:"POST",
 url:"modify_cbndtb.php",
 data: {cabinetNum:id},
 success:function (data) {
   $('#1U').val(data[0].num1);
   $('#11U').val(data[0].num2);
   $('#2U').val(data[0].num3);
   $('#12U').val(data[0].num4);
   } 
 });
```

I hope it help you

Comment: $sel->fetch_assoc() did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

modify_cbndtb.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['action']))
{   
    $q=$_POST["cabinetNum"];
    $sql="select num1,num2,num3,num4 from  hpc WHERE sysid= '".$q."';";
    $sel = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row = $sel->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row['num1'].",".$row['num2'].",".$row['num3'].",".$row['num4'];
    }
}
?>
```

your form

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="testing/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<form id="form">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
    <input type="hidden" id="cabinetNum" name="cabinetNum" value="1">
</form>
<div id="content" class="content">
1U:<input type="text" id="1U" value="">3U:<input type="text" id="3U" value=""><br />
2U:<input type="text" id="2U" value="">4U:<input type="text" id="4U" value=""><br />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#submit',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataen = $("#form").serialize() + "&action";
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"modify_cbndtb.php",
            data: dataen,
            success:function (data) {

                $(function(){
                    var valData = data;

                    var valNew=valData.split(',');
                    for (i = 0; i < valNew.length; i++) {
                        valNew[i] = valNew[i];
                        $('#'+(i + 1)+'U').val(valNew[i]);
                    }
                });
           }
        });
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: ,Thankyou.$sel->fetch_assoc() did nothing.

Comment: try this `while($row = $sel->fetch_assoc()){
            echo $row['num1'].",".$row['num2'].",".$row['num3'].",".$row['num4'];
    }`